# PHP/MYSQL Averaging each row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with X amount of columns that are labeled C1, C2, C3..to CX.  I also have a column labeled "Average" and another labeled "Target".  The "Average" column finds the average of each row in columns C1 - CX.  Is it possible for the "Average" column to dynamically change while user is filling in the form?  If so, how?

If that is not possible, then how do I have the "Average" column update its value upon submitting the form with the edited C1-CX values?

Just looking for tips on how to deal with the Averages.  I already have working C1-CX columns with pre-defined fields that save to a MYSQL database.

Comment: yes, with javascript.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Comment: It's definitely possible, I'd check out AJAX, starting with JQuery or Dojo regarding making HTTP requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event handler that triggers when any of the CX form field values have been changed (e.g. a user changing the value in it) and then re-calculate the average and display it in the average column.

Probably something like the following, assuming your CX forms are inputs:

```
document.getElementById("C1").addEventListener("input", function(){
    // Any time the user changes a value in form 'C1',
    // this function will be called so you can re-calculate
    // a new average and stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give all of them a specific class (e.g. "cx") and then with JavaScript and jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/yw3Hy/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cx").change(function() {
        var count = 0;
        var sum = 0;
        $(".cx").each(function() {
            count++
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        var avg = sum/count;
        alert(avg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql trigger to update your `Average` field automatically when your records updated.

Run this trigger on your database (e.g. for 3 `CX` field):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.Average = (NEW.C1 + NEW.C2 + NEW.C3) / 3;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also here is an introduction to mysql triggers maybe useful:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/